# Geometry information of QRubberBand giving SIGSEGV

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault

I am designing a Qt application using Qt Creator. As a part of the application, I need to be able to get position, height and width information of `QRubberBand` before I `hide()` it. For that purpose I tried to use the following logic, which is given in the documentation of `QRubberBand`:

```
void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    origin = event->pos();
    if (!rubberBand)
        rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, QSize()));
    rubberBand->show();
}

void Widget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, event->pos()).normalized());
}

void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubberBand->hide();
    // determine selection, for example using QRect::intersects()
    // and QRect::contains().
}
```

And defined rubberBand as below in the private section of the header file:

```
QRubberBand *rubberBand;
```

After doing that it works well. To go to the next step I defined the following integers as well (private section of the header):

```
int rubX;
int rubY;
int rubWidth;
int rubHeight;
```

And I tried to get geometry information before hiding `rubberBand` in `mouseReleaseEvent` similar to the following:

```
void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubX = rubberBand->x();
    rubY = rubberBand->y();
    rubHeight = rubberBand->height();
    rubWidth = rubberBand->width();        
    rubberBand->hide();
}
```

When I added those codes, the program runs, but when I try drawing the `rubberBand`, the program crashes giving `SIGSEGV`.

So here are my questions:

- **Why this is happening?**
- **Is it possible to accomplish my goal by slightly editing the code?**
- **What should I do to get what I want?**

I know that I have done a foolish mistake, but I have not found it yet. Do not hesitate to comment if you want to get more information about the question.

Comment: Are you initializing `rubberBand` to `nullptr` in the `Widget` constructor?

Comment: @G.M. No, I haven't done it yet

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for your help, I have done it and it is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code and comments you appear to be assuming that the `rubberBand` member will automatically be initialized to `nullptr`.  However, it's actually uninitialized making the following...

```
if (!rubberBand)
    rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
```

result in undefined behaviour.

Change your `Widget` constructor to include an explicit initialization...

```
Widget::Widget ()
    : rubberBand(nullptr)
{
    ...
}
```

Better still, just make `rubberBand` a non-pointer member...

```
QRubberBand rubberBand;
```

and initialize it in the constructor with...

```
Widget::Widget ()
    : rubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this)
{
    ...
}
```